# Convert String received from C to Java String

Tags: java, android, c, string, sockets

I would like to convert a string that I send out from C, and receive it as a string value in Java.

Here is my code for sending string in C.

```
strcpy(buffer,"hello");
send(clientSocket,buffer,4096,0);
```

And my code to receive string in Java.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(LoginActivity.getSocket().getInputStream()));
String str = in.readLine();
```

However, when I do a toast, the str value comes out in weird symbols. How do i solve this?

Comment: `send(clientSocket,buffer,4096,0);` ---> `send(clientSocket,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1,0);`

Comment: Plus `\n`. And then there is the charset encoding on both sides.

Comment: @JoopEggen so i do, "hello\n"?

Comment: Yes, and `new InputStreamReader(..., StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` or something (US_ASCII). And length 5+1; strlen.

Comment: @JoopEggen Alright noted! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should change

```
send(clientSocket,buffer,4096,0);
```

to

```
send(clientSocket,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1,0);
```

In this way you send only your string, not the whole buffer.

Moreover I think that

```
in.readLine()
```

hangs expecting for a newline char that isn't string sent.

Comment: Also, use StreamReader instead to take care of multiple bytes character.

Comment: @Learning2code Easy fix: add `\n` at the end of string

Comment: Wow! It works! Gahhh, looks like I have to read up more on the strlen function and also readline. Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `InputStreamReader(InputStream in, String charsetName)` constructor version and pass charsetName used to create text in C